# SQL find next followup within X number of days (joins comparing datetimes)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to write a query that's pulling dates from one table of schedules and seeing if they had followup contact from another table within X number of days.

I have a query that's something like this but it's not doing the checks properly.  My logic seems right in my head but I guess it's not right:

```
select
appointments.person_id
,appointments.date
,nextDate.minDate
,case when datediff(d,appointments.date,nextdate.minDate) <= 3 then 'yes' else 'no' end as 'within3days'

from appointments
left join
(
select person_id, min(date) as minDate
from calls
group by person_id
) as nextDate on appointments.person_id = nextDate.person_id and appointments.date <= nextDate.mindate
```

Any ideas?
I'm thinking I'm not exposing the appointments date properly to the join to the calls table

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/404fa/5

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? This doesn't look in any way like it would tie appointments together to identify follow-up appointments. I assume the same person can have 2 appointments where the 2nd is not necessarily a follow-up to the first? Also SQL Server supports analytic functions so whatever query you end up using should probably involve the LAG function.

Comment: correct.  I'll sql fiddle in a few minutes.  Thanks

Comment: On a side note: using `datetime`as a column name might not be a good idea, as it's the name of a data type.

Comment: you're missing `group by person_id` inside your left join

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b39318/1
@jpw yeah.  I was just writing up some pseudocode

Comment: Are you not actually using sql server (as you tagged)? Looks like you're using MySQL.

Comment: sorry.  I'm scrambling through it.  switched it to mssql
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/404fa/5

Comment: @jpw it didn't seem to work on your fiddle if I added some extra data
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21212

Comment: @jawz101 Yeah, I noticed what the problem was, the min(calls date) needs to be correlated to the appointment. And I believe a correct answer was just posted by Brian DeMilia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you use `apply` for this purpose.  I think it is the easiest way to express your logic:

```
select a.person_id, a.datetime, c.datetime as nextdatetime,
       (case when datediff(d, a.datetime, c.datetime) <= 3 then 'yes' else 'no'
        end) as within3days
from appointments a outer apply
     (select top 1 c.*
      from calls c
      where c.person_id = a.person_id and
            c.datetime > a.datetime
      order by c.datetime
     ) c;
```

Comment: I think that did it.  I need to look this one over and let it sink in.  I'd never used outer apply before.
Thanks!

Comment: @jawz101 . . . I don't know if it helps, but, in this case, `outer apply` is a lot like a correlated subquery.  Except, you can put it in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
select a.person_id,
       a.date,
       c.date as first_call_after,
       case when datediff(d,a.date,c.date) >= 3
            then 'yes' else 'no' end as within3days
  from appointments a
  left join calls c
    on a.person_id = c.person_id
   and c.date = (select min(x.date)
                   from calls x
                  where x.person_id = c.person_id
                    and x.date >= a.date)
 order by a.person_id, a.date
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/404fa/14/0

You are joining to the person's first call, any call. What you really want is the first call **occurring after the appointment on the given row.**

Edit, just changed x.date > a.date to x.date >= a.date in the event someone places a call immediately after their appointment. In my above statement I should have said "occurring on or after..."

Comment: I think this one works too.  I'm having probs testing it on my real data but it could just be me.
For some rows it's picking up call dates that precede an appointment for me.

Comment: Can you put together a fiddle where that is the case? I don't see how that would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I "think" this is basically what you're trying to do. Using a windowing function to partition the data off allows you to build this type of logic. You're going to have to look at this and tune it to get what you want, but you should be able to see how you partition by one or more columns and then select a row set with the "between" clause.

This logic is commonly used to build moving averages so I've included a sample of that code as well for your reading enjoyment. For me, the windowing function more clearly represents the problem, but getting used to the syntax takes a few minutes.

```
select [appointments].[visit_id]            as [visit_id]
   , [appointments].[person_id]         as [person_id]
   , [appointments].[date]              as [appointment_date]
   , [calls].[call_id]                  as [call_id]
   , [calls].[date]                     as [call_date]
   , min([calls].[date])
       over (
         partition by [appointments].[person_id]
         order by [calls].[date] desc
       rows between current row and 3 following ) as [minimum_date]
from   [dbo].[appointments] as [appointments]
   join [dbo].[calls] as [calls]
     on [calls].[person_id] = [appointments].[person_id]; 


with [average_builder] as (
select [symbol], [date],[close],[0003_day_ave],
avg([close])
over (
    partition by [symbol]
    order by [date] desc
    rows between current row and 2 following
) as [average]
from  [equity].[data]
where [0003_day_ave] is null)
update [average_builder] set [0003_day_ave] = [average];
```

Comment: Well I like all of these answers because they all probably work with a different strategy.  Yes, it is reading material!
Thanks